# How do I fix redirect on login attempt with Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting a very strange bug that's only appearing when I publish to Azure. When I go to sign in from my portal-app, the browser will get redirected to a -different- app in my architecture, on it's version of the same "sign in or sign up" page. If I then attempt to sign in again, it'll do a second challenge to Azure(Controller.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false), but instead of being asked for my credentials, it'll simply redirect me back out to my Index, with me logged in. If I sign out from both apps, I'll eventually be able to view correct behavior from my portal-app(when I press sign-in from that app, it takes me to Azure, and asks for credentials) And I repeat: This behavior doesn't happen while in debug on my localhost, it's only something I'm experiencing after publishing to Azure.

Also, a new data point since I started having this problem: I recently launched a new Azure App, and now the "redirected to" app is that one, instead of the one it was previously when this first started.

The challenge I'm issuing:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> {
   {
      AzureB2CConstants.B2CPolicy, _Policies.SignInPolicy
   }
};
AuthenticationProperties authProps = new AuthenticationProperties(dictionary) {
    RedirectUri = "/"
};
return new ChallengeResult(
    AzureB2CConstants.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationScheme,
    authProps);
```

Comment: Are you using Azure AD? How do you authenticate users? Please provide some configuration code.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda I added the challengeresult's construction that I'm calling to let people sign in using Azure(the policies are in B2C)